# Is there a way to connect it to the PC without using direct serial port (or parallel port)?

Tags: laptop, ports, sensors

I want to connect a sensor to my PC ([MPU-9250 Nine-Axis (Gyro + Accelerometer + Compass) MEMS MotionTracking™ Device](https://invensense.tdk.com/products/motion-tracking/9-axis/mpu-9250/)).

I know that in the device drivers list there is the category "Sensors" (at least on Windows).

I know that I can connect it through a serial port and write my code using an Arduino, but I want to be able to see it as an actual sensor.

I also know that on my old ThinkPad T61, there is an accelerometer so it must be connected in a way or another.

(After the switch o Windows 10 on it I can't access it anymore)

So, is there a way to connect it to the PC without using direct serial port (RS232) (or parallel port)?

Is it possible through an USB port (with a microcontroller of some sort, like an Arduino Leonardo)

**Update**:

- I found that sensors are HID devices so I can connect mine using USB.
- I found this interesting document that explains that it is possible to connect sensors through USB: [Document from usb.org](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hutrr39b_0.pdf)

Comment: Many sensors in PCs nowadays are simply internal USB devices. For example, on a MacBook running macOS the keyboard, track pad, etc… are connected to the system either via an internal USB connection or via the Apple T2 chip. So when you say you want to avoid serial or parallel connections, that’s not really possible. The sensor would need to be an HID device connected via USB and you would then need to get — or write — drivers to get data from that device. While you say you want to avoid using an Arduino, at the end of the day that might be the simplest way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Your assumptions are mostly incorrect.  That particular 9-axis sensor uses I2C and/or SPI interfaces.  A *"direct serial port (or parallel port)"* cannot be used to connect such a device.  Sensors that have I2C and SPI interfaces are intended for internal  or embedded situations, and not suitable for hot-plugging to a PC.  That is what USB was /is designed for.  But USB is a far more complicated interface, at both the hardware and software levels.

Comment: You're vague as exactly what you have.  If it is just the sensor chip by itself, then it's probably useless.  That sensor chip needs support circuitry as well a controller (board) for connection to a PC using USB.  E.G. refer to the [eval board user guide](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/AN-IVS-0001EVB-00-v1.4.pdf), page 16, for communications via USB with a host computer.